# scalamock / specs2: What if I don't have assertions? Expectations only in IsolatedMockFactory

Tags: specs2, scalamock

If I don't actually have an explicit assertions like `count must_== 1` a in Specs2 test, I'd get an error indicating no implicit could be found.

```
// doesn't compile
class Example extends Specification {
  "You need an assertion" >> {
    // hello!
  }
}
```

Fair enough.

But if I also use scalamock's `MockContext`, I can rely on just *expectations* rather than assertions; mock something and scalamock will verify methods are called etc;

```
class MockExample extends Specification {
  "I can use 'expectations' here instead" in new MockContext {
    val foo = mock[Foo]
    (foo.bar _).expects(*).once
    // no explicit assertions
  }     
}
```

However, if I try and share context setup by mixing in `IsolatedMockFactory`, I'm back to the compiler failure. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
// doesn't compile
class AnotherMockExample extends Specification with IsolatedMockFactory {
  val foo = mock[Foo]
  "I can't use 'expectations' here any more" >> {        
    (foo.bar _).expects(*).once
  }  
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `(foo.bar _).expects(*).once`? You can solve the compiler error by creating an `org.specs2.execute.AsResult` instance for that type.

Comment: Great, that got me cooking. Thanks. Do you want to elaborate in an answer and I'll mark it as correct? I create a `AsResult` as you suggested that basically always returns `Success`; seems a bit dodge... any thoughts on how bad it might be? I mean, I create one for `Unit` which seems to undermine the whole ethos, assuming the restriction is there to encourage using assertions..?

Comment: I don't think that you have to create a "catch-all" `AsResult` instance for `Unit`, you just need an instance for the types returned by ScalaMock expressions. BTW this would be a good ScalaMock PR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example in specs2 accepts anything that has an `org.specs2.execute.AsResult` typeclass instance. Since `(foo.bar _).expects.once` is of type `CallHandler` you can create an `AsResult` instance for `CallHandler` that just evaluates the value and returns `Success`

```
 implicit def CallHandlerAsResult[R : Defaultable]: AsResult[CallHandler[R]] = new AsResult {
    def asResult(c: =>CallHandler[R]) = {
      c
      Success
    }
 }
```

Since failures are exception-based in ScalaMock this should result in an exception being thrown if some mock expectation is not satisfied.